# Xamarin Forms Material Visual: localize "Cancel" button

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have custom renderer for `MaterialPickerRenderer`. Which looks like this:

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(BorderlessPicker), typeof(BorderlessPickerRenderer), new[] { typeof(VisualMarker.MaterialVisual) })]
namespace KitchenAssembly.XF.Droid.CustomRenderer
{
    public class BorderlessPickerRenderer : MaterialPickerRenderer
    {
        public BorderlessPickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null || e.NewElement == null)
                return;

            Control.BoxStrokeWidth = 0;
            Control.BoxStrokeWidthFocused = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to add localization of "Cancel" button to it. It looks like this:
[image]

As you can see "Abbrechen" is German version, which is default for this app. But when I change app language to any other it's not updated. How can I fix it?

Comment: is the phone language on German too? Because that looks like the OS dialogue, then you would need to change this on your custom renderer dialog like it's explained [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f31eaefe-6088-408b-a34b-aaca4c91b022/change-texts-in-xamarinforms-views-independently-from-os-settings?forum=xamarinforms) or create a field that displays a dialog on click with [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup) and you can use your localization strings to change for whatever language you want instead using a custom renderer

Comment: Phone language is english.

Comment: Did you try the custom render in the link FabriBertani provided?